# error MSB4018: The "<exec>" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

i am getting this error with visual studio 2010 and .net framework 4.0.
Not able to see any relevant solution for this especially with VS2010.
any comments/suggestions pls.

error MSB4018: The "" task failed unexpectedly
error MSB4018: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. 
error MSB4018:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) 
 error MSB4018:    at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) 
...
...
...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in our code. It will be fixed for the next release. Please see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/3f0ae1f8-1be6-48b3-997d-90e163aeab48) to help work around it.

> What a stupid bug. I have logged it for v4.0. The only workaround I can find short of removing IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat is to add a CustomWarningRegularExpression like `.*{.*` so that you get warnings instead of errors or a crash.